# Find the last occurrence of consecutive (time) rows in a dataframe which match query

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following data frame:

|  | Date_time | Probe_loc | Temp | Humidity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-04-08 12:30:00 | KY_North | 65 | 40 |
| 1 | 2021-04-08 12:31:00 | KY_North | 65 | 40 |
| 2 | 2021-04-08 12:32:00 | KY_North | 65 | 40 |
| 3 | 2021-04-08 12:33:00 | KY_North | 65 | 40 |
| 4 | 2021-04-08 12:30:00 | KY_South | 65 | 41 |
| 5 | 2021-04-08 12:31:00 | KY_South | 66 | 39 |
| 6 | 2021-04-08 12:32:00 | KY_South | 66 | 39 |
| 7 | 2021-04-08 12:33:00 | KY_South | 66 | 39 |
| 8 | 2021-04-08 12:34:00 | KY_South | 68 | 40 |
| 9 | 2021-04-08 12:40:00 | KY_South | 65 | 41 |
| 10 | 2021-04-08 12:41:00 | KY_South | 66 | 39 |
| 11 | 2021-04-08 12:42:00 | KY_South | 66 | 39 |
| 12 | 2021-04-08 12:43:00 | KY_South | 66 | 39 |
| 13 | 2021-04-08 12:44:00 | KY_South | 68 | 40 |

I can easily do some queries against the dataframe to return the rows that match certain criteria

So for example, lets say I want to see all entries where temp is less than 67 and humidity <=40,
I can just do:

```
qr = probe_df[(probe_df['Temp'] <67) & (probe_df['Humidity'] <=40)][['Date_time','Probe_loc', 'Temp', 'Humidity']]
print(qr)
```

And I get back the following:

```
Date_time           Probe_loc Temp Humidity
2021-04-08 12:30:00  KY_North  65 40  
2021-04-08 12:31:00  KY_North  65 40  
2021-04-08 12:32:00  KY_North  65 40
2021-04-08 12:33:00  KY_North  65 40
2021-04-08 12:31:00  KY_South  66 39
2021-04-08 12:32:00  KY_South  66 39
2021-04-08 12:33:00  KY_South  66 39
2021-04-08 12:41:00  KY_South  66 39
2021-04-08 12:42:00  KY_South  66 39
2021-04-08 12:43:00  KY_South  66 39
```

What I'd like to know how to do, is to select only the last matching value from consecutive time entries, for each probe.  So the entries at 12:33:00 and 12:43:00.

Expected output would be:

```
Date_time           Probe_loc Temp Humidity
2021-04-08 12:33:00  KY_North  65 40
2021-04-08 12:33:00  KY_South  66 39
2021-04-08 12:43:00  KY_South  66 39
```

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Comment: @sammywemmy just added expected output to the end of the question.  Thx

Comment: Something like this : ``df.loc[lambda df: df.Temp.lt(67) & df.Humidity.le(40)].groupby('Probe_loc').tail(1)``?

Comment: Ha, nice.  That was easier than i thought it would be.  Thank you much.

Comment: Well, it kind of works.  However, it doesn work if the same location is present, and later has additional consecutive time ranges.  It will only print the last entry for each probe.  I was trying to find only the last entry for each set of consecutive time ranges that also satisifed the critera.  So for example, with my data above, lets say there was another range of data from 12:40 to 12:45 for the same probe, Id want to see two entries for that probe, the 12:33 and the 12:45 entry, and the 12:33 entry for the other probe.  I can go and add more data to querstion if that would help explain.

Comment: yea, add the data with some more explanation

Comment: ok, @sammywemmy I updated, sorry for not being detailed enough first go round.

Comment: It will include the 12:42 as well right?

Comment: No, because I only want to see the last selection, of a consecutive time range.  So basically, I want to figure out if I can grab the only the last row from consecutive timeframes (no gaps in minutes).

Comment: I don't understand records (3, 4) and (8, 9). For a same `Probe_loc`, you have 2 measures at the same `Date_time`. Is it a real case? Shall we keep the last value only?

Comment: Ugg I just saw your comment, Im correcting the data, there should not be duplicate entries based on time stamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input data:

```
>>> probe_df
             Date_time Probe_loc  Temp  Humidity
0  2021-04-08 12:30:00  KY_North    65        40  # group 1
1  2021-04-08 12:31:00  KY_North    65        40  # group 1
2  2021-04-08 12:32:00  KY_North    65        40  # group 1
3  2021-04-08 12:33:00  KY_North    65        40  # group 1 <- match
4  2021-04-08 12:33:00  KY_North    67        39  # group 1

5  2021-04-08 12:30:00  KY_South    65        41  # group 2
6  2021-04-08 12:31:00  KY_South    66        39  # group 2
7  2021-04-08 12:32:00  KY_South    66        39  # group 2
8  2021-04-08 12:33:00  KY_South    66        39  # group 2 <- match
9  2021-04-08 12:33:00  KY_South    68        40  # group 2

10 2021-04-08 12:40:00  KY_South    65        41  # group 3
11 2021-04-08 12:41:00  KY_South    66        39  # group 3
12 2021-04-08 12:42:00  KY_South    66        39  # group 3
13 2021-04-08 12:43:00  KY_South    66        39  # group 3 <- match
14 2021-04-08 12:44:00  KY_South    68        40  # group 3
```

```py
qr = (probe_df["Temp"] < 67) & (probe_df["Humidity"] <= 40)

data = []
# for each location
for _, df in probe_df.groupby("Probe_loc"):
    # create groups of consecutive time
    groups = (df["Date_time"].diff(1) > pd.Timedelta("1T")).cumsum()
    # keep the most recent value that match your filter
    df = df.groupby(groups, as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x[qr[x.index]].iloc[-1])
    data.append(df)
```

Ouput result:

```
>>> pd.concat(data).set_index(["Probe_loc", "Date_time"]).rename_axis(columns="Measurement")
Measurement                    Temp  Humidity
Probe_loc Date_time
KY_North  2021-04-08 12:33:00    65        40
KY_South  2021-04-08 12:33:00    66        39
          2021-04-08 12:43:00    66        39
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  so use the -1 index with an inline function with groupby.  Makes sense.